# Can I print the data source name on Jasper Report using Jasper Studio's?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using TIBCO JasperSoft Studio to create my jasper report.  I will pass different data sources to the same report.  I tried to use $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} but only get something like "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.SortedDataSource@...".  Can I print the data source name on Jasper Report using Jasper Studio's parameters / fields / variables expression ?

My Data Source is "SUNNYSZ" as shown

[image]

And My Report Layout is

[image]

And My result is

[image]

My Question is how can I print my real data source name "SUNNYSZ" ???

Comment: What kind of information do you want to get? You can get name of *subDataset*, for example. `I will pass different data sources to the same report.` - What is a data source name for you?

Comment: details added in question what i want